# Should US State specific tags exist?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we have tags for specific US States?

We definitely have questions about state laws and politics, but I'd argue that having individual tags for each state is too localized. Here are some state tags that I've found, and with the exception of New York and California, they don't seem to be used that much. Most could likely be replaced with [us-state-laws](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-state-laws) as a more general tag.

What do people think? Should we:

1. Promote the use of US state tags
2. Remove them when not absolutely necessary
3. Keep a few, such as California, but discourage most
4. Merge them into a new, more general tag, something like [us-state-government](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-state-government)
5. something else?

[california](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/california): 27 questions

[new-york](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york): 10 questions

[florida](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/florida): 5 questions

[ohio](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ohio): 4 questions

Comment: In what sense are state tags too localized? We have [tags](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vatican-city) [for](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/malta) [places](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marshall-islands) that are far smaller than Rhode Island, and have far less population than Wyoming.

Comment: Also, is there any harm in having state tags? Have you, for example, noticed a tendency for state tags to push more useful tags out of the way? In the (very) few I checked it seemed that questions with five tags (the max allowed) were the exception rather than the rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think individual US state tags are fine in principle. In general, tags should be justified by the volume of relevant questions existent... so before anyone goes crazy and creates one for every French arrondissement (or US county), they need to consider that factor.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think we should ban them or anything. California, for example, seems to be well used and fairly helpful. But if someone creates a new tag for a single question (as I initially did for [tag: massachusetts], should we keep that and try to spread it, or remove it as unhelpful

Comment: @divibisan: That's a good question. I'm not totally sure of the best approach, so it might be worth asking separate (but not necessarily about state tags). Sometime it's probably reasonable to create tags early, and sometimes it's probably better to "wait and see" how many questions there are.